# GParted does not recognize SATA M2

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, uefi, ssd

I bought myself a new Laptop, the ASUS GL771JW with 250 GB M2 SSD drive and a 1 TB HDD.

Now I'd like to install Ubuntu 15.10 on it, but I get errors.

I downloaded the amd64 Ubuntu ISO and put it on a USB stick using `sudo dd if=/home/myuser/ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdd`. Then I load the Live OS with Unity on it and start GParted, right away getting the error message:

```
Libparted Warning

The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes.

Cancel / Ignore
```

**If I hit Cancel** GParted only shows an unallocated 7.41 GB drive on `/dev/sda` which is my USB stick. I can as well select `/dev/sdb` which is my 1 TB HDD drive, but I cannot select my 250 GB M2 SSD drive.

**If I hit Ignore** GParted shows 4 partitions on a 29.65 GB drive on `/dev/sda`:

- /dev/sda1, FS unknown, size 4 KB
- unallocated, FS unallocated, size 1.09 GB
- /dev/sda2, FS fat16, size 2.22 MB
- unallocated, FS unallocated, size 28.56 GB

I have no idea where it gets that from and I miss the rest of the 250 GB drive.

Does anyone know that problem? I tried to find some useful settings within the ASUS BIOS / UEFI-BIOS, but wasn't too successful with it. What must I do to install Ubuntu on my laptop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same trouble with an NVMe disk. That technology is quite recent and the old version of GParted in Ubuntu repo couldn't see my SSD. I resolved creating a GParted live USB with the latest version of the software.

Comment: +1 Good answer but for a more Ubuntu based solution you could add this download to your answer, it has `gparted` .debs for a newer version that should work too http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/getdeb_apps/wily/apps/getdeb/gparted

Comment: Thanx, I forgot. 0.24 at your link should be the first release that included NVMe support.

Comment: Ok, I tried it with GParted version 0.24 as a Live Disk from [gparted.org](http://gparted.org/download.php). Unfortunately it doesn't work. GParted still does not recognise my SSD drive (SD7SB3Q256G1002). Are SSDs not yet fully supported in Ubuntu? Isn't it possible to install Ubuntu on it?

Comment: Full support to NVMe was added in GParted 0.24.0-2. The version that did the trick for me just a week ago was 0.25. I suggest to retry with that version. Anyway launching the installation of Ubuntu you should be able to partition your SSD with Ubuntu disks partitioner.